# Rails/ActiveRecord query for quiz questions that have not been answered yet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm getting all questions that a student has not been answered correctly yet.

```
correct_questions = QuizQuestionResponse.where(correct: true, user_id: current_user.id, lesson_id: params[:quiz_response][:lesson_id])
questions = QuizQuestion.where('lesson_id = ? AND id not in (?)', params[:quiz_response][:lesson_id], correct_questions)
```

Is there a way I could write this in a more elegant and efficient way?

Comment: I'm confused as to why ```QuizQuestionResponse`` id attributes are compared against the id of ```QuizQuestion```?

Comment: Oops. That's an error that I have not spotted, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the original queries are incorrect, since you are using `QuizQuestionResponse` ids as a parameter for `QuizQuestion` id.

```
correct_question_ids = QuizQuestionResponse.where(correct: true, user_id: current_user.id, lesson_id: params[:quiz_response][:lesson_id]).pluck(:question_id)
questions = QuizQuestion.where(lesson_id: params[:quiz_response][:lesson_id]).where.not(id: correct_question_ids)
```

The `not` method is for Rails 4+